# Generic IIS7 hosting environment hardware requirements

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-hosting, hardware

does someone can tell me what are hardware requirements for generic IIS7 websites hosting on one Windows server where only IIS7 and FTP is installed (maybe some ranges like <100 pages - 1GB 1CPU, 100-300 - 2GB 1CPU etc).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give some indication of how much traffic your are expecting, serving 100 pages that no one is reading could easily be done on the minimum spec required for server 2008 r2.

Comment: This is very difficult question. Let's say all of them will be written in ASP.NET, daily traffic will be 50GB, half of them will be used almost all the time and half of them from time to time. This is probably not so much information and that's why I asked about "generic IIS7 Hosting environment". I have not asked only for 100 pages but for some levels of minimal hardware usage for certain number of web pages (and again I know it depends :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of pages isn't so important as what those pages are doing and how much traffic you have.  The same server with 20,000 basic HTML pages might have the same load levels as a server with 100 ASP.Net pages that have intensive database access or data processing.  My general rule of thumb is to buy the best and fastest hardware that we can afford.  Hardware is relatively cheap, so don't skimp and go with the bare minimum required.  Get a decent server with RAIDed storage, redundant power, fast hard drives, and lots of memory (4GB for 32-bit operating systems, more for 64-bit).

Also, see Jeff Atwood's [server specs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/new-stack-overflow-server-glamour-shots/) for what they're using to run Stack Overflow and ServerFault as a baseline.  These are really busy sites running on a small handful of decent servers that were pretty inexpensive to build.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx) is a link to MS's own list of requirements for running Windows Web Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This system requirements has nothing to do with real requirements for certain usage (they give only minimum anx maximum). I'm interested in real life examples if anyone is willing to share.

Comment: Given the very limited information in the question I think it was an appropriate, and valid, answer.